# Generic Bases, Covarience

Tags: c#, list, generics, addition, covariance

I have a generic base class from which other generic classes inherit:

```
public class B<T> {

    private List<T> parent;

    public bool IsInParent() { return parent.Contains(this); }

    public void Attach() { parent.Add(this); }

}
```

The two `this` give the error "cannot convert from `B<T>` to `T`. I understand that this is due to the fact that `this` could be something other that T (covariance) and therefore won't go into a `List<T>`. That much I understand.

If I state that `T` inherits from `B<T>` there is no error for the first `this` but the error for the Add `this` remains.

```
public class B<T> where T : B<T> { ..... ]
```

Now surely if every `T` inherits from `B<T>`, then every `B<T>` is a `T` and therefore should go into a `List<T>`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Now surely if every T inherits from `B<T>`, then every `B<T>` is a T and therefore should go into a `List<T>`" You've got it exactly backwards. Imagine if I said "Now surely if every int inherits from object, then every object is an int and therefore should go into a `List<int>`" I hope it's obvious how that is wrong. The correct statement is that "every T can go into a `List<B<T>>`".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The analogy was useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The two this give the error "cannot convert from `B<T>` to `T`. I understand that this is due to the fact that `this` could be something other that `T` (covariance) and therefore won't go into a `List<T>`.

I don't think you do understand it.

First: `this` is of type `B<T>`.  Imagine instead of the abstract `B<T>` we made it more concrete:

```
class Comparer<T> // I can compare two things of type T.
{
    ....
```

`this` inside `Comparer<T>` will be of type `Comparer<T>`. If you have a `List<T>`, you can put a `T` into the list.  Suppose `T` is `Apple`.  `this` can compare two apples.  The `List<T>` can contain two apples. But the `List<T>` **cannot contain two comparers of apples** because that's not its type!

Second, you don't understand what the word "covariance" means. I don't know what you think it means but my guess is that you believe that "covariance" means "assignment compatibility".  That's usually what people believe "covariance" means when they are wrong about its meaning.

"Assignment compatibility" is the property that a value of type `Apple` can go into a variable of type `Fruit`, because an `Apple` is **assignment compatible** with a storage for `Fruit`.  **That is not covariance**.

**Covariance is the property that an assignment compatibility relationship is preserved by a generic type.**

That is:  an `Apple` can go into a variable of type `Fruit`, and therefore an `IEnumerable<Apple>` can go into a variable of type `IEnumerable<Fruit>`.  The relationship of assignment compatibility **is preserved as the types are varied by making them generic**, and therefore `IEnumerable<T>` is **co-variant**; the things *vary together in the same direction*.

> If I state that `T` inherits from `B<T>` there is no error for the first this but the error for the `Add` `this` remains.

First off: **do not do this**. This is a bad pattern. It is a variation on the C++ pattern called the "curiously recurring template pattern". I have seen it used many, many times in C#, and almost always used wrong.  Avoid it.  It makes your types complicated, hard to use, hard to understand, and it makes you think that you have a constraint on your type that C# does not support.

> Now surely if every `T` inherits from `B<T>`, then every `B<T>` is a `T` and therefore should go into a `List<T>`.

And now you perhaps begin to understand why it is that this pattern is so awful.  It makes you believe completely crazy false things because it is so confusing!

Let's again make your sentence less confusing. We'll replace `T` with `Apple` and `B<T>` with `Fruit` and we have:

> Now surely if every apple is a kind of fruit, then every fruit is an apple and therefore should go into a bowl of apples".

Your conclusion is that apples are fruits, and therefore all fruits are apples, and so you can put a banana into a bowl of apples and it is still a bowl of apples.  Plainly this is nonsensical.

> What am I doing wrong?

You're building generic types that are so complicated that you can't understand them correctly.  That means that the people *using* your code will not be able to understand them either. Find a simpler way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: it explains a lot. I will try to recode without the "curiously recurring template pattern".